# gulp-uglify + Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

Trying to uglify the js files. When I use the bundle file in `index.html`. I get below error.

Below is my gulp file.

```
'use-strict'
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
return gulp.src(['vzrth.js','psrhs.js'])
.pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client'));
});
gulp.task('nodestart', function (cb) {
  exec('node ./bin/www', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'nodestart']);
```

The error I get is:

> reference error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=e

Comment: What dependency annotation are you using?  If you are using implicit annotation your service names will get renamed during minification and break your app.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of your controllers or directives?

Comment: i have provided below

Answer (score 6):

When you minify angular files you need to be aware that Dependency Injection (DI) will break if done incorrectly.

This is a minification UNSAFE example of a controller with DI:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.title = 'Minify me';
});
```

This is a minification SAFE example of the same controller with DI:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.title = 'Minify me';
}]);
```

**Why does the first example break when minifying?**

When you minify a javascript file the parameters in a function get minified to something more simple so this would be your controller after minifying:
First the unsafe example:

```
.controller('MyController', function(a, b) {
    a.title = 'Minify me';
});
```

as you can see, **$scope** got minified to **a**. **a** means nothing to Angular (unless you actually have a service defined as **a**).

Now the minify safe example:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function (a, b) {
       a.title = 'Minify me';
    }]);
```

in this example Angular knows that the first parameter is actually **$scope** because a string literal doesn't get minified.

EDIT:

If you declare a controller or directive like this (minify unsafe):

```
.controller('MyController', controller);
function controller($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.title = 'Minify me'
}
```

this would become (method 1):

```
.controller('MyController', controller);
controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
function controller($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.title = 'Minify me'
}
```

OR this would become (method 2)

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$timeout', controller]);
function controller($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.title = 'Minify me'
}
```

Comment: 'use strict';
angular.module('HeaderCtrl', []).controller('headerController',
  ['$location', '$window', '$stateParams', '$log', 'HeaderFactory', 'UserDataService',
    function ($location, $window, $stateParams, $log, headerFactory, userDataService) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.profile = []; // array of user profile details
      function init () {
      };
      init();
    }
  ]
);

Comment: The controller you provided looks completely safe for minification, are you sure you haven't made a mistake on a different controller? Try enabling [Strict DI Mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production).

Comment: can we use ng-annotate to get the required verbose. any thought on tht.

Comment: I've never used ngAnnotate myself. I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is outdated, this issue can now simply be solved by using ngAnnotate. 
This can be done like this:

```
 .pipe(concat('app.js'))
 .pipe(ngAnnotate())
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./gulp/js'))
```

first concat your files, then use ngAnnotate and then use your uglify. 
You will need 'gulp-ng-annotate' for this:

```
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
```

ngAnnotate will fix your dependency issues.